# Installing iText 7.1 fails in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, itext7

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 premium (can't use a higher version for my project).

I installed the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio from Tools --> Extension Manager --> Online Gallery.

I installed 'Common.Logging' and 'Common.Logging.Core' packages which are dependencies of iText7.

I tried to install iText7 after the previous two packages but I got an error because 'Portable.BouncyCastle' package is also a dependency of iText7.

I tried to install the 'Portable.BouncyCastle' package but got an error:

Install-Package : The 'Portable.BouncyCastle 1.8.1.3' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.

```
PM> Install-Package itext7
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Common.Logging (≥ 3.4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Common.Logging.Core (≥ 3.4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Portable.BouncyCastle (≥ 1.8.1.3)'.
Install-Package : 'Portable.BouncyCastle' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package itext7
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM> Install-Package Common.Logging
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Common.Logging.Core (≥ 3.4.1)'.
Installing 'Common.Logging.Core 3.4.1'.
Successfully installed 'Common.Logging.Core 3.4.1'.
Installing 'Common.Logging 3.4.1'.
Successfully installed 'Common.Logging 3.4.1'.
Adding 'Common.Logging.Core 3.4.1' to AF.Custom.Events.
Successfully added 'Common.Logging.Core 3.4.1' to AF.Custom.Events.
Adding 'Common.Logging 3.4.1' to AF.Custom.Events.
Successfully added 'Common.Logging 3.4.1' to AF.Custom.Events.

PM> Install-Package Common.Logging.Core
'Common.Logging.Core 3.4.1' already installed.
AF.Custom.Events already has a reference to 'Common.Logging.Core 3.4.1'.

PM> Install-Package itext7
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Common.Logging (≥ 3.4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Common.Logging.Core (≥ 3.4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Portable.BouncyCastle (≥ 1.8.1.3)'.
Install-Package : 'Portable.BouncyCastle' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package itext7
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM> Install-Package Portable.BouncyCastle
Install-Package : The 'Portable.BouncyCastle 1.8.1.3' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Portable.BouncyCastle
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

I checked in Visual Studio for updates of NuGet client from Tools --> Extension Manager --> Updates. , but couldn't find any updates.

Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that you're trying to install the current version of the package in an IDE that's 8 years old. Perhaps use an older version? [7.0.3 appears to have no dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/7.0.3)

Comment: Thanks stuartd, I installed the 7.0.3 version with no issues at all!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this below code in Nuget Package Manager Console ;

```
Install-Package itext7 -Version 7.0.3
```